# Class 'Maatwebsite\\Excel\\ExcelServiceProvider' not found - Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, laravel-4, php-5.6

I'm using Laravel 4.2, after running `php artisan migrate` I got

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider' not found in /home/forge/site/distributor-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 157
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/forge/site/distributor-portal/artisan:0
PHP   2. require_once() /home/forge/site/distributor-portal/artisan:30
PHP   3. require() /home/forge/site/distributor-portal/bootstrap/start.php:68
PHP   4. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->load() /home/forge/site/distributor-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php:210
PHP   5. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->compileManifest() /home/forge/site/distributor-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php:57
PHP   6. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->createProvider() /home/forge/site/distributor-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php:121
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Maatwebsite\\Excel\\ExcelServiceProvider' not found","file":"\/home\/forge\/site\/distributor-portal\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/ProviderRepository.php","line":157}}
```

This is what I have in `composer.json`

```
"maatwebsite/excel": "~1.3"
```

I am running on **PHP 5.6**.

> Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider

How do I avoid this ? Is this something that I did in one of my migration files  ?

Answer (score 7):

For **Laravel 4**

Add this line to *`composer.json`*

```
"maatwebsite/excel": "~1.3",
```

After changes in composer.json then run `composer update`

Add the ServiceProvider to the providers array in *`config/app.php`* like:

```
'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider',
```

Add also in alias like:

```
'Excel' => 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel',
```

Publish config file:

```
php artisan config:publish maatwebsite/excel
// The config files can now be found at app/config/packages/maatwebsite/excel
```

---

For **Laravel 5**

This will download the package and PhpSpreadsheet.just run at a command prompt:

```
composer require maatwebsite/excel
```

The *`Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider`* is auto-discovered and registered by default, but if you want to register it yourself:

Add the ServiceProvider and Facade in *`config/app.php`*

```
'providers' => [
    Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,
],
'aliases' => [
    'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,
]
```

To publish the config, run the vendor publish command:`php artisan vendor:publish` This will create a new config file named *`config/excel.php`*

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you publish after following these steps

1) add this line to composer.json

```
"maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
```

then run

```
composer update
```

2) After updating composer, add the ServiceProvider to
the providers array in `app/config/app.php` like
`'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider'`,

and alias like so

```
'Excel' => 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel',
```

3) And finally, publish for Laravel 5

```
`php artisan vendor:publish`
```

`php artisan config:publish maatwebsite/excel` for Laravel 4

I hope it helps someone.!